# Defining a function on a Euclidean Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\{x, y\}$ be a linearly independent set in a Euclidean space V.
Define $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(a) = \|x − ay\|$

I do not understand the question. How should I define that function? Compute that norm and write the value of f(a)?

Comment: When it says "define", it doesn't want "you" to define it.  It has already been defined:  your function is defined as $$f(a)=||x-ay||$$

Comment: My god I am such a dumb ass. The actual question was on the next page. I am sorry